# CSS psuedo class not working in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I have a Wordpress theme, with bootstrap, that has a navigation menu. For the last menu item I am wanting to apply a different style using :last-child.

Here is the CSS, amoungst other styles in one of many style sheets:

```
#main-nav ul.menu li:last-child a:hover {
   /* Pink Exam Timetable for Phil */
   border-bottom-color: #F501FF;
   background-color: #4B67A1;
}
```

Everything is working absolutely fine in Chrome and Firefox (as it always does) and the 'hover' is working fine in IE9 & 10 preview (on Win 7) but for some strange reason the 'last-child' is not working in IE9 & 10 (tested on 3 computers).

I've cleared the cache and tried all sorts but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Is the `li` actually the last child, or is there an empty text node or something?

Comment: @robertc: I don't think CSS considers text nodes. Or does it?

Comment: what happends if you add a `last-child` class to your css and you apply it programatically to your HTML?

Comment: Can you provide a http://jsfiddle.net of it not working?  If a simplified demo doesn't work, chances are you have some sort of specificity conflict.

Comment: @FelixKling I think you're correct, I just know there are often DOM differences due to the text nodes

Comment: What Browser Mode does IE9/10 report if you hit F12?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any issues on IE9 with this.

```
<ul>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li><a>Text</a></li>
</ul>

li:last-child a:hover {
   /* Pink Exam Timetable for Phil */
   border-bottom-color: #F501FF;
   background-color: #4B67A1;
}
```

Try this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dYxmn/)

The issue could be in your mark-up.

Answer (score -1):

***NOTE: I am talking about Cross Browsers (not just IE9...)***

last-child is not 100% cross browser friendly yet:

*Internet Explorer versions < 9, and Safari < 3.2 definitely don't support it, although Internet Explorer 7 and Safari 3.2 do support :first-child, curiously.*

....if you want to have a pseudo that works 100% the first:child would work:

You can work it out to have it reverse so the last would work for your desire (first:child method)

or go manual:

for your example you might have to do a class define like this:

CSS:

```
#main-nav ul.menu li .last a:hover {
   /* Pink Exam Timetable for Phil */
   border-bottom-color: #F501FF;
   background-color: #4B67A1;
}
```

your html

```
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">sdfds</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sdfds</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="#">dfgdrg</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: While this might be true, it does not answer the OP's question.  IE9 *does* support `:last-child`.

Comment: Agree...but this can be another way to do it....and the fact that **this IS working on my IE9(his issue/code)** could be a lower version of IE.

Comment: He says in his question that he's not